# A function that accepts: a string or a function or two objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a module in Node.js that exposes only one function named `direct`, basically a request router (Yes, I'm making my own, in an effort to learn). However, I'd like to simplify the API to just use one function. Everything else comes chained after, depending on what was `direct`-ed.

It will be accepting 3 types of input for now: A string (route) or a function (a callback) or two objects - the request and response objects from `http.createServer`:

```
direct('/');           //pass a route string
direct(function(){});  //pass callback
direct(req,res);       //pass the request and response
```

Internals for these are mine to worry. Currently I'm doing:

```
//if only one, 
if(arguments.length === 1) {
    if( typeof arguments[0] === 'string') {
        //add to routes
    } else if( typeof arguments[0] === 'function') {
        //add to callbacks
    } else {
        //return an error
    }
} else if(arguments.length === 2 && ...check if both are typeof object, not null, not instance of array...) {
    //extremely long check if both are objects
    //planning to extract the check as a function
} else {
    //return an error object
}
```

As you see, it seems like I am hard-coding much of the stuff. Also, the checks are inefficient and a bit long.

- What's an efficient way of filtering the arguments according to the given criteria?
- Is there a way to check if the objects sent in was the `request` and `response` objects of the `http.createServer`?

Comment: you can change the function to always receive a configuration object and test for the object properties only. that will shorten your checks.

Comment: Argument 2 will always be a response object since you are defining it.   If arg2 is present then arg1 is a req obj. No need to do the complex checking.

Comment: @AMember the goal of this was to simplify the function usage. Building an object just to contain that few pieces of data would go against that goal.

Comment: @Ibu What I meant was that is there a way to check if the 2 objects are *really* the `request` and `response` from Node, and not just any arbitrary object.

Comment: How strict do you want the interface to be? `instanceof` might be of use to type check `request` and `response`.

Comment: calling direct({fn:function(){}}), or direct({route:'...'}) does not look to complicated to me... and is certainly not against your goal.

Comment: I totally don't understand the question. How would that code not be efficient? Also, what do you mean by hard-coding? Do you want a generic re-usable type-checking hook?

Answer (score 1):

if you implement direct like this it might be easier:

```
direct = function(o){

  if(o['route'])
    DO SOMTHING
  }

  if(o['fn']){
    DO SOMETHING ELSE
  }
  ...
}
```

always get a configuration object that will hold the intent of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookup table based on `typeof`:

```
var handlers = {
    'string':   { n: 1, fn: function(route)     { ... } },
    'function': { n: 1, fn: function(callback)  { ... } },
    'object':   { n: 2, fn: function(req, resp) { ... } }
};
```

and then:

```
var handler = handlers[typeof arguments[0]];
if(!handler) {
    // throw a hissy fit and bail out
}
if(arguments.length != handler.n) {
    // throw a different hissy fit and bail out.
}
return handler.fn.apply(null, arguments);
```

You could also ditch `n` and use the `length` property of the handler functions:

```
var handlers = {
    'string':   function(route)     { ... },
    'function': function(callback)  { ... },
    'object':   function(req, resp) { ... }
};

var handler = handlers[typeof arguments[0]];
if(!handler) {
    // throw a hissy fit and bail out
}
if(arguments.length != handler.length) {
    // throw a different hissy fit and bail out.
}
return handler.apply(null, arguments);
```

You could further abstract the `handler.n` check into a function and then the `'object'` version of the checker could use `instanceof` to make sure `req` and `resp` are the right sorts of things. This would make your `direct` look something like this:

```
var handlers = {
    'string': {
        good_args: function(arguments) { ... },
        fn: function(route) { ... }
    },
    //...
};

var handler = handlers[typeof arguments[0]];
if(!handler) {
    // throw a hissy fit and bail out
}
if(!handlers.check_args(arguments)) {
    // throw a different hissy fit and bail out.
}
return handler.fn.apply(null, arguments);
```

If you need to handle more complexity and variability then you could replace the simple objects in `handlers` with "real" objects that support a known interface. That smells like over-engineering though, I'd probably stop at the `good_args` version.

You're pretty much building a miniature command interpreter, might as well make it look like one.

Answer (score 1):

> - Is there a way to check if the objects sent in was the request and response objects of the http.createServer?

This part is easy.

From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request):

> `request` is an instance of `http.ServerRequest` and `response` is an instance of `http.ServerResponse`

So your code would look like this, assuming that your `direct` function takes named formal parameters `a` and `b` (I think this is more readable that `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]`):

```
else if (arguments.length == 2
        && a instanceof http.ServerRequest
        && b instanceof http.ServerResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think like you, there are functions that are more elegant and more easy to use if you just pass to them the data.

Your code is correct but you are too strict. Javascript is a weakly typed language. If you begin to check the type of each parameter you'll never end and one line functions could become too complex. If you say in your docs that the function receives 2 strings then the user must pass 2 strings, it'n not your problem if he decides to pass one boolean and one function.

I'll write the following:

```
var direct = function (param, res){
  var type = typeof param;
  if (type === "string"){
    //direct("/")
  }else if (type === "function"){
    //direct(function(){})
  }else{
    //direct(req, res)
  }
};
```